# Angular 2 - Synchronous http calls using flatmap is not performing the next calls when an empty observable is returned

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, flatmap

I am performing three synchronous calls in this manner

```js
this.deletePreallocations()
     .flatMap(() => {
         return this.postPreallocations();
     })
     .flatMap(() => {
         return this.postPayment();
     })
     .takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
     .subscribe(
         () => { },
         err => {
            console.log(err);
      });
```

And each calls are like this

```js
deletePreallocations() {
      if (this.preAllocationsDeleteIds.length > 0) {
         let self = this;
         let prealloctionsDeleteIDs = this.preAllocationsDeleteIds.filter(function (item, index) { return self.preAllocationsDeleteIds.indexOf(item) === index; });
         return this.paymentsService.deletePreallocations(this.payment.ID, prealloctionsDeleteIDs);
      }
      return Observable.empty();
   }

   postPreallocations() {
      if (this.preallocationupdatedValues.length > 0) {
         return this.paymentsService.postPreallocationsCollection(this.payment.ID, this.preallocationupdatedValues);
      }
      return Observable.empty();
   }

   postPayment() {
      return this.paymentsService.post(this.payment);
   }
```

So the problem is when the returned observable is empty, it is not performing the next calls. Can someone suggest what is wrong with this code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct because `flatMap` works only with the `next` notifications and `Observable.empty()` sends only the `complete` notification and nothing else.

So what you can do is not to rely on the `next` notification and just wait until the previous Observable completes:

```
this.deletePreallocations()
     .concat(Observable.defer(() => this.postPreallocations()))
     .concat(Observable.defer(() => this.postPayment()))
     .takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
     .subscribe(
         () => { },
         err => {
            console.log(err);
         }
     );
```

I'm using `Observable.defer` that calls its callback only when you subscribe to it. Since in `this.postPreallocations()` and `this.postPayment()` you have some logic that depends on an internal state this should guarantee that these methods will be called only when `concat` tries to subscribe.